# Include blazor component into MVC view (.NET Core 3 Preview #5)

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to include a blazor component into my MVC application, but something with the endpoint routing does not seem okay.

I have a razor page (in pages/example.cshtml) and a default controller (in Controllers/Home) with views (in Views/Home/Index.cshtml).

Opening...

- [local] -> index view, Blazor works
- [local]/Home -> index view, Blazor works
- [local]/Example -> example page, Blazor works
- [local]/Home/ -> index view, Blazor DOES NOT work
- [local]/Home/Index -> index view, Blazor DOES NOT work

The script debugger says:
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - https://localhost:44342/Home/_blazor/negotiate

I tried different things in the startup file, but whatever I tried I wasn't able to make it work.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        //services.AddControllersWithViews(o => o.EnableEndpointRouting = false); -> does not change anything
        services.AddMvc(o => o.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            //endpoints.MapControllers();  -> does not change anything
            //endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); -> does not change anything
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the prerendering work, ie do you see the component in a MVC page?

Comment: Yes. If I add a break point to code initializing something in the component, the debugger will stop during the prerendering of it. Only the communication from the browser to the server does not work.

Comment: I've opened an issue about this since it's still prevalent in preview 8. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13594

Answer (score 6):

The issue on GitHub has been resolved by one of the devs: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13594#issuecomment-527821142

This is by design. You need to set the base path for the document using `<base href="~/" />` inside the `head` tag of your html page. Alternatively you can manually start blazor as in

```
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script>
        Blazor.start({
            configureSignalR: function (builder) {
                builder.useUrl(@("/"))
            }
        });
    </script>
```

although this second solution might prevent links from working properly.